# Antiparticle from the weak charge

Tags: standard-model, antimatter, weak-interaction

For the electromagnetic charge and the colour charge, every particle carrying these charge has an antiparticle having the opposite charge. Why are there no antiparticle from the weak charge?

Comment: are you referring to this weak charge?
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_charge

Comment: i don't really know what you refer to, could you elaborate or put an example of such charge present in a particle?

Comment: Yes, the weak force charge :)

Comment: Sorry, I thought in the previous message that you mentioned the electroweak charge :)

Comment: As it says on Wikipedia, the weak force charge is the coupling strength of weak neutral currents, i.e. the vector coupling of any fermion to the Z boson. You might be referring to the weak boson?

Comment: You are plain misinformed. The gluons coupling to $\lambda_3$ and $\lambda_8$ are manifestly self-conjugate, so $\bar R R -\bar G G$ and $\bar R R  + \bar G G -2 \bar B B$.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, is there a reason why only the electric and colour charge give rise to antiparticles?

Comment: What, exactly do you mean by that? The gluons couple to quarks and antiquarks, and so does the Z and the photon.  In what way do you imagine the Z is different than other vector bosons?

Comment: If you believe you have not been misinformed, look at [this summary](https://pdg.lbl.gov/2021/reviews/standard_model_and_related.html), the last term of (10.2), with (10.6a,b), which contradict your misimpression.  The Z does couple to particles and antiparticles with opposite charges, even though C is broken.

Comment: Hi Cosmas, my apologies for the unclear question, but maybe this example can help understand my confusion: a red top-quark has an anti-red top-quark with the opposite electric charge as its antiparticle. So from here, the colour and the electric charge seem to flip, but why only these two and not the weak charge?